# Stored procedure takes longer to run than direct code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Any idea how i debug the fact that direct SQL run fine but when wrapped as a stored procedure, endless runtime.
I checked the SSMS activity monitor - does not show blocked or suspended...

Comment: Go look up parameter sniffing, it's almost always this.

Comment: This should be one of the only things you ever need to read on the topic: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: does the stored proc has a name that starts with sp_ ? I read somewhere that can be a problem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: DavidG - hmm - lemme check
@alroc - awesome reference 
GuidoG - it does coz i name 'em that way - dunno why that should affect performance

Comment: Ah yes, *never* name your procedures "sp_...", that prefix implies the procedure is "**sp**ecial", not that it's a "**s**tored **p**rocedure"

Comment: I added a link in my prior comment about this

Comment: @GuidoG - Crikey - such weird behavior - I shall change the name post haste!

Comment: It can affect performance, look here https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @DavidG - Parameter sniffing is the problem -- Would you please add this as an answer so I can mark it solved?

Comment: @GuidoG - good link - I'll change the names of all my procedures - naively had I assumed `sp_` stood for `stored procedure`...

Comment: You can name them sp without the underscore if you want, that is not a problem